# IUnknown pointer reference

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dxgi, visual-c++-2013

Why is the Visual Studio compiler happy with

```
void fn(int *&i) 
{
    ;
}
```

and

```
void fn(IUnknown *const &p)
{
    ;
}
```

but not

```
void fn(IUnkown *&p)
{
    ;
}
```

where calling it looks like

```
IDXGIFactory *df = nullptr;
// init df
fn(df);
```

compiler error is

> 3   IntelliSense: a reference of type "IUnknown *&" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "IDXGIFactory *"   c:\Users\Carl\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Project5\main.cpp  29  10  Project5

The closest thing I've dug up with research is that the compiler will only do one type conversion at a time, but that can't be right because then the *const & version should break from doing a type and const conversion; however it is the &* version that actually won't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-const lvalue reference (like `IUnknown*&`) can only bind to an *lvalue*; it cannot bind to an *rvalue*.  A const-qualified lvalue reference (like `IUnknown* const&`) *can* bind to an *rvalue*.

It's easier to consider a simpler case that does not involve pointers or function calls:

```
int i = 0;

double        x = i; // (1) Well-formed
double const& y = i; // (2) Well-formed
double&       z = i; // (3) Ill-formed
```

Here, `i` is an object of type `int`.  When `i` is used in an expression, it is an *lvalue*.

In **(1)**, we initialize the object `x` (of type `double`) from `i` (of type `int`).  The type does not match, but this is okay, because there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `double`.  The "result" of this conversion is an *rvalue* expression<sup>(*)</sup> of type `double`, which is used to initialize `x`.

In **(2)**, we initialize the const-qualified reference `y` (of type `double const&`) from `i`.  Again, the types do not match, so the implicit conversion is used to convert the `int` to `double`.  The "result" of this conversion is an *rvalue*.  As noted at the beginning, a const-qualified reference can bind to an *rvalue*, so `y` is bound to the "result" of the conversion.

In **(3)**, we attempt to initialize the non-const reference `z` (of type `double&`) from `i`.  The types do not match, so a conversion would be required.  The conversion cannot be used here, because the "result" of the conversion is an *rvalue*, and as noted at the beginning, a non-const reference cannot bind to an *rvalue*.

C++ has special rules to permit const lvalue references to bind to *rvalue* expressions.  You can find out why from other questions here on StackOverflow, like ["How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)

Your case is exactly the same as this one:  the type of your argument (`IDXGIFactory*`) is not the same as the type of the parameter (`IUnknown*` or a reference thereto), so an implicit conversion is required to convert the argument to the parameter type (in this case, it's a conversion from *a pointer to a derived class* to *a pointer to a base class*).  The "result" of this conversion is an rvalue expression, however, so it cannot bind to the non-const reference `IUnknown*&`.

---

<sup>(*)</sup>It's really a prvalue; I've used the C++98 expression taxonomy in this answer for simplicity.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) for information about the C++11 value categories.

Comment: `the "result" of the conversion is an rvalue` is what I was missing. Thank you!