# why const double reference can be assigned to int but not non const one?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

Recently I have written one function which is doing some processing on double numbers but due to some change I need to do same processing for integers so to cut the long story short with simpler example as given below :

```
void display(double& arg)
{
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    int inum = 10;
    display(inum);
    return 0;
}
```

I found that above code is not compiling and giving error "reference of type "double &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "int", since the error is quite intuitive so i modified the code and changed the argument of display function to const double& arg and everything seems to be working correctly.So my question is

**What exactly is happening in the "const double&" case? A full explanation is desired?**

Now after reading some of the explanation and question link that is provided i understood that conversion produces rvalue and rvalue cannot be bound to temporaries so the only reasoning i m looking for is why conversion produces rvalue ?

Comment: Making it const allows the compiler to construct a temporary for the argument.

Comment: I believe temporaries are rvalues but here inum is lvalue so compiler converts lvalue to temporary also ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IUnknown pointer reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551510/iunknown-pointer-reference)

Comment: @Kapil The compiler needs an lvalue that is a double. Passing a reference imples that the callee can modify the value, and it doesn't make sense to pass a temporary as a reference unless it's const. Otherwise the callee could do the modification and see no effect, which would just baffle you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of the error I see: `error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'double&' from an rvalue of type 'double'`

It's clearly complaining about `double&` (which is the parameter type of the `display` function) cannot be initialized with an rvalue of type `double`. Well, `inum` was passed to the function but it's type is `int`. However, `int` can be implicitly converted to `double` and this is happening. The conversion produces an `rvalue` (i.e., temporary) `double` **but a temporary cannot be bound to a non-const reference**.

---

Changing it to `void display(const double& arg)` works because everything works the same as explained above. However, an rvalue **can be bound to a *const* reference**.

---

I don't have the official standard but the following quotes are from the [n4296 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf):

> **4 Standard conversions [conv]**
>
> <sup>1</sup> Standard conversions are implicit conversions with built-in meaning. Clause 4 enumerates the full set of such
>   conversions. A standard conversion sequence is a sequence of standard conversions in the following order:
>
> <sup>(1.1)</sup> — Zero or one conversion from the following set: lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, array-to-pointer conversion, and function-to-pointer conversion.
>
> <sup>3</sup> An expression e can be implicitly converted to a type T if and only if the declaration T t=e; is well-formed,
>   for some invented temporary variable t (8.5).
>
> <sup>6</sup> The effect of any implicit conversion is the same as performing the corresponding declaration and initialization
>   and then using the temporary variable as the result of the conversion.

Comment: Is there any way  by which it can be identified that conversion produces rvalue ?

Comment: I don't follow your question. Are you asking about a reference to the standard about implicit conversions?

Comment: Yes that will be helpful as i could not understand the reasoning that conversion produces rvalue

Comment: @Kapil I don't have an official copy but I'll look through the draft I have. However, the conversion certainly cannot produce an lvalue (i.e., something you can take the address of).

Answer (score 2):

`double&` is a reference to a double, which exists somewhere else. Usually you would use this to modify a variable which the caller provides. But, if the caller provides the address of an `int`, and you try to treat it like a `double`, things will go badly for you! The compiler also forbids calling a function like `void bar(double&)` with a temporary, like `bar(3.14)`, because trying to modify a temporary value usually doesn't make sense.

On the other hand, with `const double&`, you promise not to change the value: you are only taking it by reference in order to avoid a copy, not to modify it. Therefore, it's okay to call `void foo(const double&)` with a temporary, as in `foo(3.14)`: the compiler passes along the address of the temporary, `foo` dereferences it to get the value, and after `foo` returns the temporary disappears.

So that's what's happening here: when the signature calls for a `const double&`, and you provide an `int`, a temporary double is created (cast from the `int`), and its address is passed into `display`.

Answer (score 1):

- If `inum` was a `double`, your code will work because, your parameter is a `lvalue` (you can take its address).
- If your function signature was `void display(const double& arg)` it will work, because your *promoted* parameter is a temporary and, you can bind a `const` reference to a temporary which extends its life time to the scope of the `const reference` identifier.
- If your function signature was `void display(double&& arg)` it will work, because your *promoted* parameter is a temporary and, you can bind a `rvalue` reference to a temporary which extends its life time to the scope of the `rvalue reference` identifier.
- The difference between the previous two methods above, is that you can modify `arg` in the latter, and its C++11 and above....

In C++, You cannot bind a non const reference (specifically lvalue) to a temporary.

What happens is that there is an [implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) of `int` to `double`

Quoting [Bo Personn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13827042/1621391):

> The original case for not allowing references to temporaries was for
>   function parameters. Suppose this was allowed:
>
> ```
> void inc(double& x)
> { x += 0.1; }
>
> int i = 0;
> inc(i);
> ```
>
> Why isn't i changed?